# How to scrape aspx pages with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, web-scraping, xml-parsing

I am trying to scrape the addresses in this website - 
https://aca.accela.com/ALAMEDA/Cap/CapHome.aspx?module=Building&TabName=Building

Here is how a part of HTML looks -

```
<tr class="ACA_TabRow_Odd ACA_TabRow_Odd_FontSize">
        <td class="ACA_AlignLeftOrRightTop"><input id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList_ctl02_CB_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$dgvPermitList$gdvPermitList$ctl02$CB_0" onclick="Check(this,'ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList_hfSaveSelectedItems');" class="aca_gridview_checkbox" title="To select one record in current page."></td><td class="ACA_AlignLeftOrRightTop" style="width:60px;">
                    <div style="margin-right: 5px;">
                        <span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList_ctl02_lblUpdatedTime" css="ACA_SmLabel ACA_SmLabel_FontSize">07/10/2018</span>
                    </div>
                </td><td class="ACA_AlignLeftOrRightTop" style="width:110px;">
                    <div>
                        <strong>
                            </strong>
                        <a id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList_ctl02_hlPermitNumber" href="/ALAMEDA/Cap/CapDetail.aspx?Module=Building&amp;TabName=Building&amp;capID1=18SPV&amp;capID2=00000&amp;capID3=00039&amp;agencyCode=ALAMEDA&amp;IsToShowInspection=">
                            <strong>
                                <span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList_ctl02_lblPermitNumber1">SPV18-0037</span></strong>
                        </a>



                        <input type="hidden" id="RecordId" value="18SPV-00000-00039">
                    </div>
                </td><td class="ACA_AlignLeftOrRightTop" style="width:130px;">
                    <div class="ACA_CapListStyle">
                        <span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList_ctl02_lblType">Solar Photovoltaic System Residential</span>
                    </div>
                </td><td class="ACA_AlignLeftOrRightTop" style="width:130px;">
                    <div class="ACA_CapListStyle">

                        <span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList_ctl02_lblDescription">INSTALL A 5.12 KW SOLAR SYSTEM, ROOFTOP, FLUSH MOUNT, 16 PANELS (BLDG)</span>
                    </div>
                </td><td class="ACA_AlignLeftOrRightTop" style="width:130px;">
                    <div class="ACA_CapListStyle">
                        <span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList_ctl02_lblAddress">1623 CLINTON AVE, ALAMEDA CA 94501</span>
                    </div>
                </td><td class="ACA_AlignLeftOrRightTop" style="width:100px;">
                    <div style="white-space: nowrap;" class="ACA_CapListStyle">
                        <div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList_ctl02_panelStatus">

                            <span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList_ctl02_lblStatus">Plan Review</span>

        </div>
                        <div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList_ctl02_panelbtnRenewalDetail">



        </div>
                    </div>
                </td><td class="ACA_AlignLeftOrRightTop" style="width:100px;">
                    <div style="white-space: nowrap;" class="ACA_CapListStyle">
                        <div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList_ctl02_Panel2">




        </div>
                        <div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList_ctl02_Panel3">



        </div>
                        <div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList_ctl02_Panel4">



        </div>
                        <div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList_ctl02_Panel5">



        </div>


                    </div>
                </td><td class="ACA_AlignLeftOrRightTop" style="width:110px;">
                    <div class="ACA_CapListStyle">
                        <span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList_ctl02_lblShortNote">INSTALL A 5.12 KW SOLAR SYSTEM, ROOFTOP, FLUSH MOU</span>
                    </div>
                </td><td class="ACA_Hide">
                    <div class="ACA_CapListStyle">
                        <span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList_ctl02_lblPermitAddress">1623 CLINTON AVE, ALAMEDA CA 94501</span>
                    </div>
                </td>
    </tr>
```

I am trying to get the address from the td column. 
Here is my code in python -

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
try:
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:
    from urllib2 import urlopen

import os

from lxml import html

import requests
import csv
import sys



for page_no in range(2, 50):
    curr_page = str(page_no)
    if page_no < 9 :
        data = {
            'ctl00$ScriptManager1': 'ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$dgvPermitList$updatePanel|ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$dgvPermitList$gdvPermitList$ctl13$ctl0'+curr_page,
            'ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$generalSearchForm$ddlGSPermitType': 'Building/Solar Photovoltaic System/Residential/NA',
            'ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$generalSearchForm$txtGSStartDate': '01/01/2008',
            'ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$generalSearchForm$txtGSEndDate': '07/17/2018'
            }
    else :
        data = {
            'ctl00$ScriptManager1': 'ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$dgvPermitList$updatePanel|ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$dgvPermitList$gdvPermitList$ctl13$ctl1'+curr_page,
            'ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$generalSearchForm$ddlGSPermitType': 'Building/Solar Photovoltaic System/Residential/NA',
            'ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$generalSearchForm$txtGSStartDate': '01/01/2008',
            'ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$generalSearchForm$txtGSEndDate': '07/17/2018'

        }

    page = requests.get('https://aca.accela.com/ALAMEDA/Cap/CapHome.aspx?module=Building&TabName=Building', data = data)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')


    print('Page ', page_no)
    #print(soup)

   address = soup.find_all('tbody')
   print(address)
```

When I try to print the address variable, it just returns an empty string. When I try to print the soup variable, it returns the entire code of the website and not the data that is found when we click on search.               Can somebody please guide me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Why do you have `'id'` in quotes?

Comment: what do you mean by text value of the sapn?

Comment: should it be with ' #' ? I was googling it and saw somewhere like this.

Comment: @Onyambu I want to extract the addresses in  the link.

Comment: I only see class and style. I do not see any address. Or by address do you mean the class and style?

Comment: if you open the link and click on search, you can see addresses of the people. That is part the I am looking to extract. Alternatively in the HTML code that I posted above, in the 4th last line, there is a span there. If you go through, you can see                                                                                                         
  <span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList_ctl02_lblPermitAddress">1623 CLINTON AVE, ALAMEDA CA 94501</span>                                           I am interested in the '1623 CLINTON AVE, ALAMEDA CA 94501' part

Answer (score 0):

The method signature for find_all is `find_all(name,attrs,recursive,string,limit,**kwargs)`

You are passing in name as `span`, but then trying to use a string as a keyword argument `id`, which is incorrect.  What you probably want is

`id = 'ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList_ctl09_lblAddress'`

as your second argument.

Comment: it is still giving the error                                                                                              for row in soup.find_all('span',id ='ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList_ctl09_lblAddress'):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: Comment out `soup.prettify()`, you're turning the parse tree into a string there, and then trying to call find_all on a string.

Comment: I did that and the code is working but it is still not extracting any data. It is just printing out the page numbers

Comment: The final line of your program is printing `text`, and not `row`.  Additionally when I try to search for the specified ID, it's not found in the HTML response.  However removing the `id` filter and searching for only `span` elements does produce several matches.

Comment: I tried removing the for loop and did this                                                                                                    
address = soup.find_all(id = 'ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_dgvPermitList_gdvPermitList_ctl09_lblAddress')
    print(address)                                                                                                                     And it is returning an empty array. Why is this happening? There is clearly an id element in the page

Comment: can you share the code that you wrote with span elements which is getting you matches?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really spend the time to review every line of the scraper - the immediate problems have already been mentioned, but I think the reason you aren't getting the results you're expecting is that the response you are getting does not match what you would get if you submitted the same form data through the browser.  In my experience, aspx sites are a real pain to scrape without using some sort of browser automation e.g. selenium.  I would recommend you re-write using selenium webdriver with phantomJS headless browser.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. It seems the website is using Viewstate and scraping it is really difficult. Can you recommend some tutorials for this?